# Controller Test Error expecting <"categories/new"> but rendering with <[]>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I am just started learning Ruby on Rails. Current chapter is about testing, while I do testing it is happening like this? What do i need to do? and What should I learn more to understand testing ruby on rails ?

Here's my Controller test code.

```
require 'test_helper'

class CategoriesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @category = Category.create(name: "sports")
    @user = User.create(username: "supyaeaung", email: "supyaeaung27714@gmail.com", password: "hlaing", admin: true)
  end

test "should get new" do
    sign_in_as(@user, "password")
    get new_category_path
    assert_response :success
  end
```

Here's the error. What should I do ?

```
Error:
CategoriesControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
NoMethodError: undefined method `confirm' for #<User:0x00007fd0781e0370>
    test/controllers/categories_controller_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:CategoriesControllerTest>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller, on line 15 tries to call method `confirm` on `User` object:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `confirm' for #<User:0x00007fd0781e0370>
    test/controllers/categories_controller_test.rb:15
```

You probably didn't implement it.